# Docker host network not working

Tags: docker, docker-network

I am really confused about this problem. I have two computer in our internal network. Both computers can ping internal servers.
Both computers have same docker version. 
I run simple docker container  with  `docker run -it --rm --name cont1 --net=host java:8` command on both computers. Then ssh into containers and try to ping internal server. One of the container can ping an internal server but other one can't reach any internal server.

How it can be possible? Do you have any idea about that?

Thank you

Comment: can you display the log of this command in the two servers : "sudo docker network inspect bridge"

Comment: `cat /etc/resolv.conf` on the failing host. Also, show the ping error, is it a timeout or unresolvable.

Comment: I do not know how it works now. I reinstall docker on mac and now it is working. Thank you very much guys.

Answer (score -4):

connect container to other systems in the same network is done by port mapping .
for that you need to run docker container with port mapping.
like  -  docker run -it --rm --name cont1 -p host_ip:host_port:container_port java:8

e.g.,  docker run -it --rm --name cont1 -p 192.168.134.122:1234:1500 java:8

NOTE : container port given in docker run is exposed in Dockerfile

now for example container ip will be  -  172.17.0.2 port given in run is :1500

Now the request send to host_ip(192.168.134.122) and host_port(1234) is redirect to container with ip (172.17.0.2) and port (1500).

See the binding details in iptables -L -n -t nat

Thanks